# Getting values from different tables with identical columns into an array

Tags: mysql, iphone, sql, objective-c

My SQL-request looks like this

```
SELECT Objects.name, Elements.name, Labels.name....
```

I write values from this request into an array, like this:

```
while([results next]){

[arrayObjects addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Objects.name"]];
    [arrayElements addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Elements.name"]];
    [arrayLabels addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Labels.name"]];
      ...

}
```

I see this message: "Warning: I could not find the column named 'objects.name'"

But if I write

```
while([results next]){

[arrayObjects addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
    [arrayElements addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
    [arrayLabels addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
      ...

}
```

then I have only the last value for all arrays.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try, I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

Instead of each column using the "same name" like this:
    "SELECT Objects.name, Elements.name, Labels.name...."

Try this:
    "SELECT Objects.name as O_name, Elements.name as E_name, Labels.name as L_Name ...."

then, you can use the unique column names:

```
[arrayObjects addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"O_name"]];
[arrayElements addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"E_name"]];
[arrayLabels addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"L_name"]];
  ...
```